# Replacing very high/low observation differences w/ averages to create an adjusted time series a good outlier adjustment method for time series data?

Tags: time-series, outliers

I have a monthly time series that stretches about 18 years.  I examine the over-the-month differences in a time series and observe that 3 or 4 OTM values are very extreme.  I can identify these values by flagging values that are over 2.5 standard deviations from the mean.  I then replace these values with the average of the OTM values that are remaining.  Lastly, I apply the adjusted OTM values backwards from my last observed value, giving me an adjusted time series without the outlier values.

**Are there any good reasons why this method should not be used?**

I find that since I am removing these extreme values, the variance of my models are much lower and my confidence intervals are smaller.  So I believe I am better identifying the overall trend of the time series.